# Special arrangement of columns in Desktop and re-order columns in Mobile responsive using Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Can anyone please help me solved below scenario using Bootstrap 4 alpha version?

I have different layout for Desktop and Mobile.

For **Desktop**, layout is looking like,

```
.............................................
. ------------- ------------- ------------- .
. .  1        . . 2         . .   3       . .
. .  Col-4    . . Col- 4    . .           . .
. ------------- ------------- .  Col-4    . .
. --------------------------- .           . .
. .   4                     . .  With     . .
. .   Col-8                 . .  some     . .
. .                         . .  height   . .
. .                         . .           . .
. --------------------------- ------------- .
.............................................
```

For **Mobile**, layout is looking like,

```
...............................
. --------------------------- .
. .   1                     . .
. .   Col-12                . .
. --------------------------- .
. --------------------------- .
. .   2                     . .
. .   Col-12                . .
. --------------------------- .
. --------------------------- .
. .    3                    . .
. .   Col-12                . .
. .                         . .
. .   With                  . .
. .   Some                  . .
. .   Height                . .
. --------------------------- .
. --------------------------- .
. .   4                     . .
. .   Col-12                . .
. .                         . .
. .                         . .
. .                         . .
. --------------------------- .
...............................
```

I have tried with pull and push, but have no result.

I want this solution using CSS only.

I had JavaScript solution, but for that I need to re-initialize the **3rd** column and that is heavy component.

Here is my current implementation: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheda91/5uwd0f2v/)

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far

Comment: Bootstrap 4 alpha is completely and totally OUTDATED! The most recent is Bootstrap 4 beta 3 and the good news is: there will be no breaking changes between this beta 3 and the final release of Bootstrap 4.

Comment: @WebDevBooster, yeah I know that bootstrap alpha version is outdated, but I don't have permission to update it in our organisation. I think, there is no such difference between alpha and beta.

Comment: Wrong! There are huge differences between that alpha and the beta 3. It will break your layout, that's for sure.

Comment: @ZimSystem here is my current implementation -> https://jsfiddle.net/bheda91/5uwd0f2v/

Comment: *"I don't have permission to update it in our organisation"* Does your organization use BS 4 **alpha** in production?

Comment: @Klooven Yes, we use Bootstrap 4 alpha version in production.

Comment: You should use responsive order classes (beta [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes), alpha [docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#order)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox started with alpha 6, so the beta really wouldn't make a huge difference in this case (although the [class names have changed from alpha-6 to beta](https://medium.com/wdstack/upgrade-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-to-beta-ca582f15ee32)). Bootstrap 4 (stable) is out today (1/18/18).

When using flexbox, the cols in each row are the same height, which won't work for your desired desktop layout. I would use `d-md-block` on the `row` to override the `display:flex` on larger (md) screens. Then use `float-left` and `float-right` to position the cols on desktop. The flexbox will still kick in on smaller screens so the floats will be ignored and cols will stack vertically as expected.

https://www.codeply.com/go/sTvrYlB1V0

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row h-100 d-md-block d-flex">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 float-left">
      1 Some content
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 float-left">
      2 Some content
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 special-height float-right">
      3 Some other content
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 special-height-small mt-2 float-left">
      4 Special content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, your solution works! I tried same but I forgot to add float-left and float-right. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try like this :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Div 1</div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Div 2</div>

       <!-- Only Visible For Mobile And Tablets -->
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-sm">Div 3</div>

      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Div 4</div>
   </div> 

    <!-- Only Visible For DeskTop -->
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">Div 3</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is is for the outdated alpha version. It's totally outdated.

Comment: @WebDevBooster , Alpha and Beta whatever it is , concept remain same for all version.

Comment: then post your answer , commenting is easy , show answer , share your knoledge.

Comment: And you shouldn't comment about things you are clueless about.

Comment: @WebDevBooster , you do your job , im doing mine . downvoting my answer does't  increase your knowledge.

Comment: @SaurabhMistry actually, I place Angular4 component inside all columns. So, in responsive it will re-initialize Div 3 from Mobile to Desktop. As I mentioned in question, it is heavy component to re-initialize.

Comment: @SaurabhMistry No, you aren't doing your job because you haven't updated your answer and haven't deleted your wrong comments.

Comment: @SaurabhMistry actually Div 3 is important. Div 1 + Div 2 + Div 3 -> Div 4 (this is summary). So, can't put Div 3 below Div4.

Comment: @Bheda91 , ok , i have to find some other way